# How to write a generic type guard in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

## Not Working Type Guard

I'm trying to write a generic type guard for different generic `Token` types but it's not working. My current approach looks like:

```js
export function isToken<T extends Token>(token: any): token is T {
  for (const key in keyof T) {  // (1) for every key in the given token type T
    if (  // check if one of the two criteria are not
        !(key in token) ||  // the key is not in the token or
        typeof token[key] !== typeof T[key]  // (2) the type for that key-value-pair is not the
                                             // same as in the given token type T
    ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

But TSC complains that:

- in line `(1)`: `Cannot find name 'keyof'.ts(2304)` - so the `keyof` keyword does not work
- in line `(2)`: `'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

How can I fix my type guard?

## The Tokens

The tokens are simply types to describe different JWT payloads:

```js
const type Token = {
  userId: string;
}

const type LoginToken extends Token = {
  role: 'User' | 'Admin'
}

const type EmailVerificationToken extends Token = {
  email: string;
}
```

## Current Type Guard

I was able to write a generic token verification function but I still have an extra type guard for token type:

```js
// for each token type I have a function like below
// this is what I'm trying to handle with a single generic type guard
export function isVerificationToken(token: any): token is VerificationToken {
  return typeof token.userId === 'string' && typeof token.email === 'string';
}

export function verifyVerificationToken(token: string) {
  return verifyToken<VerificationToken>(token, isVerificationToken);
}

function verifyToken<T>(token: string, tokenTypeCheck: (token: any) => token is T) {
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.jwtSecret);
  if (tokenTypeCheck(decoded)) {
    return decoded;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: `const type Token extends Object = {` is not TypeScript.  What is that?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/W4OQKm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: TypeScript types do not exist at runtime; they are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types).  It seems like a lot of this question is conflating the static type system of TypeScript with runtime JavaScript code.  When I read `const key in keyof T` I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Consider how you would write all of this in pure JavaScript  and then we can imagine adding types to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that Typescript doesn't exist anymore at runtime. It is transpiled into JavaScript and therefore you cannot do runtime type evaluations (like you might do in C# with Reflection or similar), since JavaScript doesn't have any types. So passing `T` as a generic parameter to a function and then using it in a non-static way (to dynamically compare property types, etc.) isn't possible. To make this work you'd have to provide an object of that type to the function and then use it to evaluate member types.

The other problem is that you're using `keyof` to get a list of all keys in an object, although that's not what the `keyof` keyword does. [see: TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html). As we've established: there are no types at runtime, so `keyof` will only work in a static context.

A working solution to your problem (although obviously not as elegant as you might expect it to be from looking at concepts present in other languages like c#, etc.) would be to pass an object of the type `T` to your function, and instead of using `keyof` you would use `Object.keys` to get all the keys of the object.

```js
export function isToken<T extends Token>(expected: T, token: any): token is T {
  for (const key in Object.keys(expected)) {
    if (!(key in token) || typeof token[key] !== typeof (expected as any)[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

// Or a bit shorter:

export function isToken<T extends Token>(expected: T, token: any): token is T { 
  return Object
    .keys(expected)
    .every((key) => key in token && typeof token[key] === typeof expected[key]);
}
```